# @zxing/ngx-scanner angular library can't read all types of barcodes

Tags: angular, qr-code, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

We are facing an issue with the @zxing/ngx-scanner angular library.
In fact, this library can’t support this type of barcode:

[image]

Any idea on how to fix this problem?

Comment: 1. Improve the barcode algorithm by yourself. 2. improve the image quality. 3. find a new barcode SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange since this is a standard 2 of 5 bar code, and I'm pretty sure the Zxing app does support these, so maybe is a missing feature in the angular library. You should see if you can set some flags to specify which bar codes you are going to scan, in this case this should be the [Intervaled 2 of 5 bar code](https://www.barcode.ro/tutorials/barcodes/interleaved2of5.html).

But if you know for sure that the library doesn't support these kind of codes, than the only option you have is to change library